# Kafa : How does Kafka stores and retrieves offset for each consumer-group?

Tags: apache-kafka, offset

I'm not exactly looking for API to accomplish this rather internal implementation detail.

I know that recent versions of Kafka stores offsets for consumer-group in a special Kafka topic 
__consumer_offset.

My questions are :

What exactly is the data structure residing in this topic ?

When a conumer-group dies and comes up how does Kafka **look-up** for the offset in Topic-Partitions till which that consumer-group had consumed last time?

As far as my understanding is , Kafka topics are not suited for looking-up data : for examples : for queries like :

`Select *offset* from __consumer_offset where consumer-group-name=*consumer-group* and topic=*topic-1*`

Basically , I want to know the internal details of __consumer_offset or anything utilized for consumer offset management.

I read this wiki page https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Offset+Management , but couldn't understand the in-memory data structure part.

Answer (score 3):

Every consumer group is assigned a particular partition in the __consumer_offsets topic based on it's hash.

Then, offsets are simply written as messages to the __consumer_offsets topic.

To keep this topic from growing too large, periodically older offsets of a given consumer group are deleted.

For reads, the Kafka broker loads this data into memory as part of startup so that every request for offset doesn't cause disk I/O. Since only the latest offset is accessed frequently, in normal operation this doesn't amount to much data to be kept in memory.

Comment: Does it mean for every new concumer-group , Kafka will create a new partition in __consumer_offset topic ?

Comment: No, the partition count is constant. Multiple groups share the same partition.

Comment: @hoodakaushal, `the reads are from memory` - gr8 to know. But is the model to read this data from memory the same as with any other partition i.e using FIFO consumer model.